# Difference between count() and find().count() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is the difference between, I basically wanted to find all the documents in the mycollection.
`db.mycollection.count()` vs 
`db.mycollection.find().count()`?

They both returns the same result. Is there any reason why would somebody choose the `count()` vs the `find().count()`? In contrast to the fact that `find()` has a default limit applied (correct me if I'm wrong) to which you would have to type "it" in order to see more in the shell.

Comment: Type `db.mycollection.count` without the brackets into the shell and you will see the method calls in there with the last line being `return this.find(query).count();` which basically says that unless you included special modifiers such as "skip" or "limit" then it is basically executing the same statement, even with a query. Even in the command form, there is essentiall no difference in the underlying execution.

Comment: The shell truncates the results for convenience. The MongoDB API actually does not truncate anything. In other words: `find()` has no such limits.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`db.collection.count()` and `cursor.count()` are simply wrappers around the [`count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/) command thus running `db.collection.count()` and `cursor.count()` with/without the same will return the same *query* argument, will return the same result. However the `count` result can be [inaccurate in sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/#behavior).

> MongoDB drivers compatible with the 4.0 features deprecate their
> respective cursor and collection count() APIs in favor of new APIs for
> countDocuments() and estimatedDocumentCount(). For the specific API
> names for a given driver, see the driver documentation.

The [`db.collection.countDocuments`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#db.collection.countDocuments) method internally uses an [aggregation query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#mechanics) to return the document count while [`db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/) returns documents count based on metadata.

It is worth mentioning that the `estimatedDocumentCount` output can be inaccurate as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/#behavior).

Answer (score 22):

`db.collection.count()` without parameters counts all documents in a collection. `db.collection.find()` without parameters matches all documents in a collection, and appending `count()` counts them, so there is no difference.

This is confirmed explicitly in the [db.collection.count() documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/):

> To count the number of all documents in the orders collection, use the
>   following operation:
>
> `db.orders.count()`
>
> This operation is equivalent to the following:
>
> `db.orders.find().count()`

Answer (score 4):

As is mentioned in another answer by sheilak, the two are equivalent - except that `db.collection.count()` can be inaccurate for sharded clusters.

The [latest documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters) says:

> count() is equivalent to the db.collection.find(query).count()
>   construct.

And then,

> **Sharded Clusters**
>
> On a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() can result in an
>   inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration
>   is in progress.

The documentation explains how to mitigate this [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645) (use an aggregate).

Comment: It is inaccurate even when the db isn't sharded if the document count is very high.

Answer (score 4):

**db.collection.count() is equivalent to the db.collection.find(query).count() construct.**

**Examples**

**Count all Documents in a Collection**

```
db.orders.count()
```

This operation is equivalent to the following:

```
db.orders.find().count()
```

**Count all Documents that Match a Query**

Count the number of the documents in the orders collection with the field ord_dt greater than new Date('01/01/2012'):

```
db.orders.count( { ord_dt: { $gt: new Date('01/01/2012') } } )
```

The query is equivalent to the following:

```
db.orders.find( { ord_dt: { $gt: new Date('01/01/2012') } } ).count()
```

As per the documentation in the following scenario db.collection.count() can be inaccurate :

1. On a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() without a query predicate can result in an inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration is in progress.
2. After an unclean shutdown of a mongod using the Wired Tiger storage engine, count statistics reported by count() may be inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you are using some kind of pagination like:

```
find(query).limit().skip().count()
```

You will not get the same result as

```
count(query)
```

So in cases like this, if you want to get the total, I think you might have to use both.