# Mongo DB, document count mismatch for a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I have a collection User in mongo. When I do a count on this collection I got `13204951` documents

```
> db.User.count()
13204951
```

But when I tried to find the count of non-stale documents like this I got a count of `13208778`

```
> db.User.find({"_id": {$exists: true, $ne: null}}).count()
13208778
> db.User.find({"UserId": {$exists: true, $ne: null}}).count()
13208778
```

I even tried to get the count of this collection using MongoEngine

```
user_list = set(User.objects().values_list('UserId'))
len(resume_list)
13208778
```

Here are the indexes of this `User` collection

```
>db.User.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "user_db.User"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "UserId" : 1
                },
                "name" : "UserId_1",
                "ns" : "user_db.User",
                "sparse" : false,
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

Any pointers on how to debug the mismatch in counts from different queries.

Comment: It is interesting and surprising behavior. Can you try running db.User.count({"_id": {$exists: true, $ne: null}}) and db.User.count({"UserId": {$exists: true, $ne: null}}) and post the result.

Comment: The count is - 13208778 for both the queries

Comment: I don't think it is possible. As far as I know _id will be primary key always and it will always exist in all documents and can't be null. So db.User.count() should always be >= 13208778. Can you try running db.users.count() again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

refer to this [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#behavior)

> On a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() can result in an inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration is in progress.

Also, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666330/difference-between-count-and-find-count-in-mongodb)

If you are not using sharding cluster, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715466/incorrect-count-returned-by-mongodb-wiredtiger)

The basic idea is `db.{collection}.count()` might do some tricks to make it fast to return a count, and it might be not accurate, use a `count()` with query should be accurate.

Comment: JohnZeng - This is a standalone mongo instance with no replica and sharding enabled.

Comment: If you are not using sharding, check this: [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715466/incorrect-count-returned-by-mongodb-wiredtiger)

Comment: Thanks John.. it worked. Will accept and up-vote if u move the above comments of yours to the answer

Comment: Editing is Done.